# Update laravel migration to nullable without changing datatype

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 6, I have a table `companies` and I want to change the column `card` to nullable.

I created a new migration and I can change it using

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->double('card')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

But the problem is `doctrine/dbal` only supports some specific datatypes to update.

> Error: Unknown column type "double" requested. Any Doctrine type that
> you use has to be registered with
> \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the
> known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap().

Is there any way I can update this column to nullable without touching its datatype? or any DB statement?

I can use

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `companies` CHANGE `card` `card` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL;');
```

but I am concern is this right way to do?

Answer (score 0):

according to Laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes):

> The following column types can be modified: bigInteger, binary,
> boolean, date, dateTime,  dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json,
> longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time,
> unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger, unsignedSmallInteger, and uuid.

so if your column is not from those types it will **not** be able to change

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that but I don't want to change datatype just want to make it nullable.

Comment: sure, change it to nullable is kind of changing